# XML Dom Tree Equivalent in Xcode

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am in the process of converting an application which is written in javascript into objective-c.

One of the functions is called 'getXML()' and is used to read an XML file and convert it into a Dom Tree.

I was wondering what the equivalent would be in objective-c. Coming from a web-based background I am not really sure what to use instead of a Dom Tree. I have found Dom Tree packages online which can be used within X-Code but I would ideally want to use a method which is equivalent to a dom tree and is built into x-code.

Could someone recommend what to use instead?

Kind Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often people use built-in SAX parser, `NSXMLParser`,though you have to go through some effort if you want the full tree. For more information, refer to its [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or see the [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i).

Also see [How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).